# How do I leave a loop when time runs out while waiting for input?

Tags: c

I am working with embedded controls and C which are new to me. I cannot figure a way to terminate the `while` loop if time runs out and the user does not enter input. The `if` in the loop is there to break the loop if a switch is moved but I cannot get to it unless a key is pressed.

```
while(overFlows < wait_time() && input == 10)
{
    input = getchar();
    input = input - 48;
    if (SS) break;
}

if (input >= 8 || input != ans)
{
    BEEPBEEP = 0;//on
    currentCounts = 0;
    printf("Incorrect");
    while(currentCounts < 169);
    BEEPBEEP = 1;//off
}
else if(input == ans)
{

    BILED0 = 0;//green on
    BILED1 = 1;
    score += (10 - (10*overFlows)/waits);
    currentCounts = 0;
    while(currentCounts < 338);
}
```

Comment: Use [`select()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/select).

Comment: Hi, I don't know if such kind of function available in C. If this functionality is very essential for you, you can write a assembly code for the same and generate an object file with masm assembler( if in windows) and link the object file into your C program. I did such kind of work long back so exactly don’t remember the assembly code now. You can check online for the same. Also you can check for windows programming  or if in unix, check for unix system call.